# My script is failing in JSLint

Tags: javascript, closures, jslint

I would have a question.
The following script is not going through JSLint without error.
Please do not vote me down. This script is only for learning purposes to understand better the closures. If you know it better than please post your solution.

The problem is when I check the code with JSLint I get the following error message:

> JSLint was unable to finish.
>   43.8Expected ';' and instead saw '}'

Here is my script

```
var c = document.querySelector("#c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var path = function () {
        return {
            innerTri: function (x, y, width, height, fill, stroke) {
                x = x || 0;
                y = y || 0;
                fill = fill || "yellow";
                stroke = stroke !== undefined ? stroke : fill;
                if (width === undefined || height === undefined) {
                    alert("You need to provide width and height");
                    return false;
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x, y);
                ctx.lineTo(x = x + width, y);
                ctx.lineTo(x, y = y + height);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = fill;
                ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();

            },

            outRect: function (x, y, width, height, stroke) {
                x = x || 0;
                y = y || 0;
                stroke = stroke || "black";
                if (width === undefined || height === undefined) {
                    alert("You need to provide width and height");
                    return false;
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x, y);
                ctx.lineTo(x = x + width, y);
                ctx.lineTo(x, y = y + height);
                ctx.lineTo(x = x - width, y);
                ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    } //this is the position 43.8
    var a = path();
    a.innerTri(225, 225, 50, 50, "yellow", "green");
    a.outRect(200, 200, 100, 100, "blue");
```

If I put there a semicolon then I get error message to every each line.
The script works as I expected but I can not do anything with this error.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it wants to. But when I put one then I get error to every each line. Please copy the code to JSLint and you will see

Comment: Thank you @mhodges Apart from the JSLint's error what do you think about the code?

Comment: Check out my answer and see if that's what you're looking for to make JSLint happy.

Comment: To be completely honest with you, I can't speak too much to the quality of the code. I don't work with canvas very often, so I am not sure as to best practices when it comes to setting stroke, fill, making lines, etc - I only know the basics. As far as the JavaScript itself goes, you are defaulting values, which is good; you're using meaningful variable names, which is good; formatting looks good. I'd say for `var c = document.querySelector("#c")` since you are selecting on the id, you should use `getElementById("c")`, as it's much faster than querySelector. Other than that, it looks fine imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you were working with extremely strict linting rules.

Here's a list of things I needed to change to get the linter to be happy:

- Put semicolons after the return statement and the path function declaration
- Put a `"use strict";` statement at the top of the `path` function
- Remove inline variable assignments inside `lineTo()` parameter list
- State that you are using `window` as a global object (in JSLint settings)
- Call `window.alert()` instead of just `alert()`
- State for JSLint to assume this code will be used in a browser (in JSLint settings)
- Ensure that each level of indentation is exactly 4 spaces from the previous level of indentation

Here's what the resulting code would look like:

```
var c = document.querySelector("#c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var path = function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        innerTri: function (x, y, width, height, fill, stroke) {
            x = x || 0;
            y = y || 0;
            fill = fill || "yellow";
            if (stroke === undefined) {
                stroke = fill;
            }
            if (width === undefined || height === undefined) {
                window.alert("You need to provide width and height");
                return false;
            }
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            x = x + width;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            y = y + height;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = fill;
            ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();

        },

        outRect: function (x, y, width, height, stroke) {
            x = x || 0;
            y = y || 0;
            stroke = stroke || "black";
            if (width === undefined || height === undefined) {
                window.alert("You need to provide width and height");
                return false;
            }
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            x = x + width;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            y = y + height;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            x = x - width;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
};
var a = path();
a.innerTri(225, 225, 50, 50, "yellow", "green");
a.outRect(200, 200, 100, 100, "blue");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and this very good explanation. It helps me a lot to understand it better. I use VS Code and it does the indentation for me what works very well but it is good to know what JSLint expects from us. I did not know it wants 4 spaces indentation at each level. One thing is not clear yet. Why did you need to move the variable assignment out from the `lineTo()` parameter list?

Comment: @LászlóPéterVarga Well, while it still works, it is typically bad practice to pass an assignment into a parameter list that is expecting an expression. That is why the linter barks at you for doing that, so I had to move the variable assignments to the previous line and just pass the updated variable value into the function.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting ";" at the end of line(42) above the line in question? Try placing it at both lines and run it again.

UPDATE:
Add "use strict"; at the beginning of you script. Tell JsLint to tolerate "whitespace mess". Add ";" on line 42 and 43. Run JsLint and now you'll see real errors:

```
Unexpected statement '=' in expression position.
           ctx.lineTo(x = x + width, y);
Unexpected statement '=' in expression position.
            ctx.lineTo(x, y = y + height);
Unexpected statement '=' in expression position.
            ctx.lineTo(x = x + width, y);
Unexpected statement '=' in expression position.
            ctx.lineTo(x, y = y + height);
Unexpected statement '=' in expression position.
            ctx.lineTo(x = x - width, y);
```